# SAP Hybris in Dell laptop with upgrade (SSD)

Tags: java, sap-commerce-cloud, hybris-data-hub

I am using a Dell Inspiron 5548 (3yrs old) which has Intel i5 (2.2ghz, 4 cores), 8gb DDR2 ram, 1TB HDD. But everything is running slow when I start the hybris server.

Do you think upgrading the hard disk to SSD will help in running the IDE and server faster?

Should upgrade Ram from 8gb to 12gb?

Or buy a new laptop? Advise which will be good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Official recommendations from SAP can be found here - https://help.hybris.com/1811/hcd/8c6b9a8186691014bd8dd9635cabfaff.html

As for development, recommended hardware is

- **CPU**: Quad Core, for example, i7
- **RAM**: 16 GB
- **HDD**: SSD

Minimum requirements less strict.

Personally, I'd say it depends on the project size. I'd recommend you to use SSD, cause Hybris build process is very disk intensive and frequent `clean all`, `init`, `update` operations may slow development process a lot.

Additionally, I'd like to recommend:

- in case you are using Windows, measure your antivirus impact. For instance, Windows Defender slows down build process up to 500% due to real-time virus protection. Some details can be found at https://discuss.gradle.org/t/why-is-gradle-so-much-slower-on-windows-ntfs/20108
- consider using Linux distribution for development. Event VirtualBox VM with Ubuntu works faster than Windows for all SAP Hybris related tasks;
- to configure a tool for HotSwap (JRebel, DCEVM, etc.) to avoid frequent restarts and rebuilds.

Answer (score -1):

need to upgrade your ram , it's required minimum 16GB is required to run hybris and other application in machine